# Update entire column based on first row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of dates in a SQL Server table. This was a fixed table that I now am adding a form for a user to change the dates. The column has about 200 dates, each row increases by 14 days. If the first date is 1/1/2018, the next row is 1-8-18 and so on.

I have a `DatePicker` on a form (and a button) if that date changes, I want all the rows in the column to change adding 14 days to the result. I want to enter the first row only and have the rest change.

This is simple in Excel, no clue how to do this in T-SQL. Thanks

Comment: Is there some other value that you can update based on?
`UPDATE Table1 SET Date = 'newdate' WHERE 'valueX' = 'valueXfromExcel'`

Comment: Are you sure you want to update the data? I'd suggest to just modify the displayed data on your script. `date('Y-m-d', strToTime( $dateFromDB . " +"  . $daysOffstet . "days" ))` for example

Comment: First NOT USING EXCEL.  This list of dates are pay periods every two weeks. they are already hard coded in the table. The table is used to call and display the dates. However,,,, Every once in a while the company changes the pay out periods.  I need to be able to adjust the table just by entering a "First DAte" in a date box on a form.  I thought about looping through the column but i am sure there is a better way.

Comment: I could modify the displayed data with a script, but the user needs access. it can't be dependent on development.  the program goes to many users.

Comment: So assuming that you are changing the pay period date, I would think that the safest way would be to (1) select the pay period where the first changed date would occur, then (2) enter the updated starting (or ending, depending on what you save) date, and apply the same date update for all later dates. You need to be sure that you do not update previous pay period dates.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this a point to start. Maybe you can find a better way to fill or create the table @AmountOfdays but this can help you put you on track.

```
DECLARE @AmountOfDays TABLE  
    ( RowNumberForExpand int );


Insert into @AmountOfDays (RowNumberForExpand) Values (1)
Insert into @AmountOfDays (RowNumberForExpand) Values (2)
Insert into @AmountOfDays (RowNumberForExpand) Values (3)

DECLARE @DateToEvaluate DATETIME = (Select [DateToTest] FROM   [dbo].[tablefortestingdates])

Select DATEADD(day,RowNumberForExpand * 14,@DateToEvaluate) as NewDate FROM @AmountOfDays
```

Comment: I am trying to do this as simple as possible.  Maybe this will help.  Here is the sql to update the first row. This is a query, so i hard coded the dates for the first row so i could experiment in SSMS.

Comment: Update Paydates  set checkissued = '1-5-18', TwoWeeksFrom = '12-16- 
    17', TwoWeeksTo ='12-23-17', RunDateFrom = '12-10-17', RunDateTo = 
    '12-23-17' where Id =1

Comment: i need the second through 200 row to add 14 days to each date. i forgot how to set a code block.  not on here much sorry for not following protocol.

Comment: Maybe you can create a while to add the values in the table variable and use it to create the data with the dates.